# How to use mouse click and drag to zoom in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new to D3 and would like to implement a click-drag-zoom similar to what is shown here: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-time-series

I already have a line graph I have built, but am confused as to how to implement this.

I guess I need some JS event handlers to find where my mousedown and mouseup happens. But how do I create the shading that occurs on the graph when the user is dragging?

Answer (score 5):

You'll probably want to use a `brush` to do this in `d3.js`.  You can see an example that I put together at http://bl.ocks.org/1962173 which does something similar.

The relevant code is:

```
var brush = d3.svg.brush()
    .x(x)
    .extent([d3.time.monday(now),d3.time.saturday.ceil(now)])
    .on("brush", display);
```

where `display` is a function that redraws data based on the current extent of `brush`. This way you don't need to try and hook your own handlers or even worry about resizing the highlighted region at all.

Comment: Answer from 2012 save me so many time in 2023 ;)